# How to customize devise for another language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have rails app which is going to be deployed in non-english country (Poland). I'm not able to find which files should I have to edit to translate ALL devise default strings into polish (form labels, default e-mails, buttons, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

Set default locale (config/application.rb)

`config.i18n.default_locale = :pl`

If you still wanna write your own, you can add something like in your I18n files

```
pl:
  devise:
    sessions:
      signed_in: 'Podpisana w powodzeniem.'
```

More info on GitHub https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#i18n

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yup, saw that already. But there are only notice/error messages. Still searching for buttons, form labels and default e-mails.

Comment: For rest of the things, you need to create pl.yml (perhaps for en.yml too) file in config/locales folder. There you can define all the translations. 

Connect with me, if you need further help with it. dushyant133@gmail.com

Comment: K, I''l try this later and give you a feedback. Thanks!